# How to read part of string into smaller string

Tags: c, pointers

I am reading a line from a .txt file. My goal right now is to read the first word of the line. I have the line stored in a string declared `char *text`. Then I have a double pointer to that string `char** charReader` which will read the letters of the string. I am trying to read the characters in one by one into a new string `char* word`, and stop when I hit a space, however I have gotten a segmentation fault in doing so.

Here is my code to perform that function:

```
    while(isalpha(**charReader) != 0){
        word[i] = **charReader;
        charReader++;
        i++;
    }
```

My goal is to output the value of `word`. But my code seems to be giving me a segmentation fault.

Comment: Do you a pointer to a sequence of pointers to single characters (`charReader++`), or do you have a pointer to a pointer to a sequence of characters (`(*charReader)++`)?

Comment: Your use of `charReader` in the snippet above is quite awkward. It is impossible to see how it has been declared and initialized without you providing [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).. Either `charReader` is an *array-of-pointers* that that on access is converted to a *pointer-to-pointer* or you  originally have a *pointer-to-pointer* and have allocated storage for some number of pointers, or you have passed *address of* using `charReader` as the parameter. How this is done is material to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `charReader` is a pointer to a pointer to char (you can think of it as being an array of strings or a matrix of chars), while the variable `word` is a string (an array of chars). Therefore, when you do:

```
word[i] = **charReader;
```

you are trying to make an assignment involving incompatible types (treating a double pointer to char as if it was a char). That's why you are getting an error.

To copy the first word of a string into another string, you can try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char text[] = "This is a string with multiple words.";
    int i = 0;  
    while(i++ < strlen(text) && text[i] != ' ');  //seek for the index of the first space character in "text"

    char *word = malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(char)); 
    strncpy(word, text, i); //"word" now stores the first word of "text"
    printf("%s\n", word);

    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```